# EF6 Updating 3 tables in one go

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database with 3 tables

Table
**Customer**

```
CustomerID  (PK)

Name
```

Table
**Order**

```
OrderID       (PK)

CustomerID    (FK)

OrderDate
```

Table
**OrderDetailLine**

```
OrderDetailLineID

OrderID       (FK)

Price

ProductCode
```

What I would like to do in the Entity Framework is add 1 customer, then add several different Orders, each with many OrderDetailLine all relating to the first customer inserted.   I have hooked up all the relationship in SQL Server and imported them into EF model.  All no problems.  I can insert 1 customer and many orders and OrderDetailLine **first time** all records get inserted ok into the correct databse tables

I am looping around customer and orders in a file adding then adding the customer and orders to the database

But when I want to add another order for the same customer( I am getting a Primary key violation on Customer with CustomerID).  EF is trying to re-insert the same customer after my initial context.SaveChanges();

So, how do I stop EF from trying to add the same customer when using the same datacontext?

I have been going around in circles for hours and getting the same error

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Order_Customer\". The conflict occurred in database \"xxxxx\", table \"dbo.Customer\", column 'CustomerID'

The customer is newly created along with the order and orderlines. But it works first time and I get the CustomerID back from EF. But when I add new order and orderlines after the inital context.savechanges(); I get the FK error

Comment: Did you try to create a new customer, or did you get the customer via EF and then add the order to it?

Comment: Show us some code, if you are using `var customer = new Customer();` stop right now and use `var customer = context.Set<Customer>().Add(context.Set<Customer>().Create());` -- otherwise, you dont get proxy object and your `CutomerId` stay 0 even if you set your `Customer` reference.

Comment: Hi the customer was newly created along with the order and orderlines.  But it works first time and I get the CustomerID back from EF.  But when I add new order and orderlines after the inital context.savechanges(); I get the FK error.

Comment: @user142617 Can you post the code for the models?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time.

The problem was I was just calling `DataContext.SaveChanges()` with adding the entities to the correct model.  For example:

```
Customer.Order.Add(customerInfo);
```

Well it was my lack of understanding.